# Is there a functional difference between _ListSubscribers and _Subscribers with respect to STATUS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views

Does anyone know if there is a difference between the **STATUS** fields for the **_ListSubscribers** and **_Subscribers** system tables?  From what I can tell the data should be the same, but when I run a query against each I get different counts for **Status = 'Active'**

_ListSubscribers count is 1,127,401

_Subscribers count is 1,134,250

Difference of almost 7K records -- any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this analysis?

Comment: Client is trying to understand how many subscribers are still subscribed (status = 'active') and I'm getting different results when running queries in the child and parent BUs.

Comment: There's a business unit status and an overall status at the parent.  The scope of unsubscribes are configured per business unit in Administration.  Analyzing a tracking extract of subscriber data will be the most accurate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Status of a subscriber on a list (`_ListSubscribers`) is not the same as the overall status in All Subscribers (`_Subscribers`).

Lists are sub-sets of All Subscribers for which SFMC maintains status.  Lists are sendable.  Publication Lists are not.

You can be `unsubscribed` from a List and still be `active` in All Subscribers.

All Subscribers represents every subscriber in the entire Enterprise 2.0 account, not just a single business unit.  Business unit membership and subscriber status are maintained in a hidden data view.  The `_Subscribers` data view does not accurately reflect business unit status or membership. (This has been a frustration for many people working in the platform for a really long time.)

The most accurate business unit membership and status come from a tracking extract that specifies the business unit.

Comment: Thanks Adam.

What is the impact when we're evaluating list data from a child BU against the parent All Subscribers list versus the All Subscribers list in the child?

I ask because my number drops significantly (approx. 770K records) when I remove the ent. prefix, but there is definitely over 1mm records as that is how many will receive an email.

Comment: Updated my answer with some additional details.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs still today is the most accurate method to do a tracking extract? So is not accurate to only do a query over the _Unsubscribe and that hidden DV I'm guessign is not accesible, correct?

Answer (score 0):

list_subscriber data view is specific to Business unit where as Subscriber data view is specific to Enterprise.
That's the reason you are getting some extra records